# calculate total hours spent and total cost by person

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

There are two tables

A table: 50000 rows with emp_name,date,hours_worked

B table: hourly_rates and name of about 100 people

I need to calculate total time spent and total cost per employee.

I have tried below query and it gives sum of total_hours but emp names are repeating.

```
SELECT A. Name ,sum(A.hours_worked) as total_hours ,sum(B.hourly_rates) as hourly_rates from    
    `soy-antenna-242009.Nik.Employee`  A 
      INNER JOIN 
    `soy-antenna-242009.Nik.cost`  B

on A. Name = B. name 
group by A. Name,A.hours,B. hourly_rates
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `A.hours,B. hourly_rates` from `group by`

```
SELECT A. Name ,sum(A.hours_worked) as total_hours ,sum(B.hourly_rates) as hourly_rates 
from `soy-antenna-242009.Nik.Employee`  A 
      INNER JOIN `soy-antenna-242009.Nik.cost`  B on A. Name = B. name 
group by A. Name
```